# AWS Workflows Not Executing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have about 300 workflows running, about half of them failed soon after I made the call to start workflows. I expected them to fail because one of activities did not return the desired result to proceed the next activity.

BUT another half of them list as Active Executions, for an hour and then all went Time Out (because I set the workflow time out 1hr), during that hour, it seems like the workflows got choked and stop even they are listed as active.

I am trying to understand this behavior but I am not sure why it happened. Is it because the workflow workers get stuck somewhere?

Comment: I'm confused.. How is this a **programming** question? How is Flash involved in this issue? Your **Title** and **Description** says two different things : Is it the list itself (SWF/Flash app) that is not working, or the workfows themselves that are not working? Read your words _"It seems like the workflows got choked and stop **even [though] they are listed as active**"_ then read again your **Title** claiming that _"SWF list of active workflows is not executing"_

Comment: I've edited the **Title**, it makes it seem the problem is in the SWF list itself not executing (Flash won't work) when you really mean that the Workflows themselves are not working (just happens to be in listed within SWF app)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is AWS SWF (Simple Workflow), not Flash. I edited the tag. I suggested to keep SWF in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Start from looking at workflow execution histories of the failed workflows. They contains full log of all events as well as identities of the workers that picked up workflow and decision tasks.